# Create / Manage dynamic TextEditingControllers

Tags: flutter

I got a ListView.builder that generates n number of elements and I am looking at adding a controller for each of them. I have seen some approaches of adding a controller to a list of controllers and then access them by the index however I am just wondering how will this impact the performance of the screen if lets say you have 20 controllers? Are there some best practices for this scenario? Should you even go down this line or avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to introduce a `Widget` for all items in list.
Make sure you dispose in a correct place for the performance.
Also I  request to store the user entered value with the object of item will help to restore on scrolls.

Eg:

```
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const YourWidget({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);
  final YourItem item;

  @override
  State<YourWidget> createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.text = widget.item.enteredValue;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: (value){
        widget.item.enteredValue = value;
      },
      ...
    );
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class YourItem {
  String? id;
  ...
  String enteredValue = '';
}
```